# People picker in SharePoint 2010 not returning users properly

Tags: people-picker, ldap

I am using SharePoint 2010 environment. Our people picker was working fine until today until a user has complained she is not getting any emails from SharePoint.

When I went to check her permissions my people picker is giving the result as
 `System.Byte[]` in results of people picker.

I had a doubt on that and checked for other users it is giving the same result as "`System.byte[]`".

I log on to my servers and checked my LDAP properties and all the properties are giving the same result `System.Byte[]`.

Can anyone help me out with this behavior from LDAP in SharePoint? Did anyone had faced this kind of issue ever?